# Common CSS style for all GridView

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

If I have many pages in my website likes

- PageOne
- PageTwo
- PageThree
- PageFour

and I have one `asp:GridView` in each page

- PageOne(GridOne)
- PageTwo(GridTwo)
- PageThree(GridThree)
- PageFour(GridFour)

I want to change all of gridViews' appearance in unique style .

I don't want to set style with `CssClass` likes

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridOne" runat="server" CssClass="style">
</asp:GridView>
```

and I don't want to use their IDs .
Is there any way to change all of gridViews' styles such as

- Header style
- Row style
- Footer style
- Selected Row style
  by using some CSS !

Comment: you can 'Auto Format...' you gridview in design view, press the arrow on the right side of the gridview. cheers

Comment: Try to set Gridview properties on eachpage in Code file.

Comment: Yes Sander H , that's suitable approach . But I don't want to do it for all GridViews . If I have 10 GridViews , I've to change 10 times .That's what I don't want !

Comment: For example > `h2{font-size: 1.5em;}` in css file will change all `h2` font-size of entire project . I want to change GridViews' style likes this :)

Comment: As you know that asp.net grid view will be converted to HTML. If you want to do this there is some risk involved. You have to style for td, th and divs. If you are trying to color those then other elements which has these tags will also have the same style. Even a normal table will have the same style as your grid view.

jQgrid will be an option. jQGrid uses the styles of jQuery UI so you will get uniform layout through out your website for all the grid views.

Comment: why wont your use CssClass? thats seems a bit ridiculous to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without setting a CSS class property on your gridview - nor would you want to as you risk affecting other elements in your code.

This article has an example of the CSS classes that you can use to style a gridview: http://evonet.com.au/creating-a-great-looking-gridview-with-filtering/

All you need to do is then add CssClass="Gridview" to each of your Gridview, which I realise in your question is not what you want, but I think is the best way,

Answer (score 0):

I've recently come across the same issue, and I've used [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings) to apply a style to all GridView tables. If you use this CSS, then you can apply a padding of 5px to all td's within a GridView

```css
    table[id*=GridView] td{
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

You can change to take off the td, use a th or whatever, but this should do it. I do realise this is 7 years after the fact, but useful to know.

UPDATE: This is working on the assumption that all GridViews have the default id added by Visual Studio - if you changed the ID's, then this will not work.

Comment: This assumes the id of every grid view contains "GridView".

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. The legacy solution I'm working on has been built that way - all controls created with the default ID assigned. This is a caveat.